# Not able to set time zone on ArchLinux

Tags: timezone

I would like to set my timezone to Asia/Kolkata. Here is the error I see on using `timedatectl`:

```
$ sudo timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Kolkata
Failed to set time zone: Invalid or not installed time zone 'Asia/Kolkata'
```

And here is the output from `timedatectl status`:

```
               Local time: Tue 2020-11-03 12:33:38 UTC
           Universal time: Tue 2020-11-03 12:33:38 UTC
                 RTC time: Tue 2020-11-03 12:33:38    
                Time zone: n/a (UTC, +0000)           
System clock synchronized: yes                        
              NTP service: active                     
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

I am using a valid timezone:

```
$ timedatectl list-timezones | grep Kolkata
Asia/Kolkata
```

Looks like my zoneinfo file is messed up:

```
$ cat /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_GB.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `timedatectl list-timezones | grep Kolkata`.

Comment: @terdon I have added more information. Please help if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata` is malformed. I would guess you inadvertently ran a command and redirected the output to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata`. Luckily, the fix is easy, just reinstall the `tzdata` package:

```
sudo pacman -S tzdata
```

And then you will be able to change the timezone normally:

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Kolkata
```